# Issue in calling api function of a jar which uses dll file

Tags: dll, jar, java-native-interface

**My Task:** I am using Hansoft (tool for agile Project Management) sdk to use its api function to extract data from our locally implemented Hansoft Server.

**Current Status:**
My development environment set up is as follows:
  Java – 1.7.0.51 (64-bit),
  Eclipse - Juno Service Release 2 for Windows 64-bit and
  Windows 7 – 64 bit.

Most of the api functions (native functions) in jar have been implemented in C++, so the sdk has both the jar and dll file (based on my development envrionment, I am using hpmsdk.jar and HPMSdkJavaJNI.dll from skd's folder directory (HansoftSDK_7_502\Win32\JavaSdkx64\lib)). You can download the sdk zip HansoftSDK_7_502.zip from "Hansoft SDK & integrations" section in http://www.hansoft.com/support/downloads/

I created an java project in Eclipse and added Hansoft api jar(hpmsdk.jar) in project build path and added dll (HPMSdkJavaJNI.dll) to the jar's(hpmsdk.jar) native library location. Following is my program structure and library path.

[image: Program Structure]

[image: Library path]

**Problem Encountering**: When I run the sample java program from Eclipse, I am getting the error “sessionOpen Failed with error: The SDK could not be found in the current path. (null)” displayed in the Jframe as follow:
[image: Jframe]

As I mentioned, I have added the dll file but I am not sure why I am getting the SessionOpen failure. This error is occurring in the code where the first usage of dll function is called from jar in executing the function HPMSdkSession.SessionOpen (HansoftSDKSample_SimpleJava.java from skd directory HansoftSDK_7_502\Samples\SimpleJava\src). I have given correction value in the parameters pointing to our local Hansoft server and credentials.

```
m_Session = HPMSdkSession.SessionOpen("localhost", 0000, "Company Projects", "SDK", "SDK", m_Callback, null, true, debugMode, 0, "", "", null);
```

I have tried various options and spend considerable amount of time in fixing this issue but I am finding difficult to sort this issue. Let me know if I need to reference any other dlls or any alternatives to sort this issue at your earliest.

Anyone with any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a issue in Java 7 to load the path variable either from eclipse or windows path variable. I set the dll path in parameter  of SessionOpen method and it seems that dll is getting picked up. Program is running fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across the same problem with Hansofts SDK on Linux using OpenJDK 1.7. 
The dll requested is the main SDK dll (HPMsdk.).
To solve this i followed Anandhas advice in the comment and called SessionOpen like this:

```
m_Session = HPMSdkSession.SessionOpen("localhost", 0000, "Company Projects", "SDK", "SDK", m_Callback, null, true, debugMode, 0, "", "/path/to/sdk/dll/folder", null);
```